# Adjusting all text in DOM tree with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to capitalize all the (user-visible) text in a HTML file.  Here is the obvious thing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def upcaseAll(str):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str)
    for tag in soup.find_all(True):
        for s in tag.strings:
            s.replace_with(unicode(s).upper())
    return unicode(soup)
```

That crashes:

```
File "/Users/malvolio/flip.py", line 23, in upcaseAll
    for s in tag.strings:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 827, in _all_strings
    for descendant in self.descendants:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1198, in descendants
    current = current.next_element
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'
```

All the variations I can think of crash the same way.  BS4 does not seem to like it when I replace a lot of NavigableStrings.  How can I do this?

Comment: How about using `find_all(text=True)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `str` as the function argument as this is a shadow name of python builtin.

Also you should be able to convert the visible elements by just using `prettify` with **formatter** like this:

```
...
return soup.prettify(formatter=lambda x: unicode(x).upper())
```

I have tested now and it works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

print soup.prettify(formatter=lambda x: unicode(x).upper())[:200]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   STACK OVERFLOW
  </title>
  <link href="//CDN.SSTATIC.NET/STACKOVERFLOW/IMG/FAVICON.ICO?V=00A326F96F68" rel="SHORTCUT ICON"/>
  <link href="//CDN.SSTATIC.NE
  ...
```

You can read [OUTPUT FORMATTER](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters) for more detailed information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do want to point out that the documentation you point to... uses `str` as the name of a parameter.

Comment: @Malvolio, very good spot indeed... and I believe they have made a mistake there :)

Comment: @Malvolio, actually I need to correct my above comment. I have just looked at **bs4** source code, this is not a mistake but a very smart way to implement this. **formatter** will first check if the parameter passed is *CALLABLE* -- **str** is, so is **lambda**, and in their sample, they smartly override **str** to return **str.upper(...)** to achieve upper case conversion.